# Safari can't expand elements in IOS7 webkit

Tags: debugging, safari, webkit, ios7

I just starting testing my app (Phonegap base) with ios7 and noticed that Safari won't expand any of the DOM elements in the debugger.  I checked with the IOS7 Safari and the desktop Safari won't expand those elements either, so it's not just related to Phonegap/webkit.

Is anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem,

Updating to Version 6.1 (8537.71) fixes it (the beta release available from the developer site http://developer.apple.com).